# Having issues with an else statment for UPDATE into

Tags: php, mysql

This is the if statement im trying to use

```
if ($rows['business_type'] = "Restaurant") {
$table_name = "restaurants";

}

else if ($rows['business_type'] = "Shop") {
$table_name = "shopping";

}
```

I have an isert based on that variable:

```
$updatesql = sprintf("UPDATE $table_name SET
```

If I define the variable with text ($table_name = "shopping') that works. If i just use

```
if ($rows['business_type'] = "shopping"){
$table_name = "shopping";
}
```

That works. It is ONLY when i try to use an else statment with it that it doesnt insert. It just inserts straight into the first if regardless.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It should be `==` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least == when checking for equality. You have = which is assignment.

```
if ($rows['business_type'] === "Restaurant") {
    $table_name = "restaurants";
} else if ($rows['business_type'] === "Shop") {
    $table_name = "shopping";
}
```